# PDO doesn't connect to remote mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I try to connect to remote mysql database.

```
$DBH = new PDO(
    'mysql:host='.$DB->DBHost.';dbname='.$DB->DBName,
    $DB->DBLogin, 
    $DB->DBPassword
);
```

In `$DB` object everything is OK. The properties `DBHost`, `DBName`, `DBLogin`, `DBPassword` exist and are correct. But, `$DBH` object is empty and I don't know why. Thanks.

Comment: What is the error you're getting?

Comment: No errors. Just empty object.

Comment: The PDO constructor would throw an exception if it fails and will return a valid PDO object otherwise. Are you getting any exception?

Comment: apokryfos, no, I don't see any exceptions. Only empty $DBH object.

Comment: Exprator, if it connected. why when I try $DBH->rollBack I get expection - "Uncaught Error: You're trying to decode an invalid JSON String: <pre>[PDOException] 
There is no active transaction (0)"

Comment: Can you dump `$DBH`?

Comment: @localheinz, "PDO Object()"

Comment: Well, that looks great. What's the problem, then? Are you executing any queries that fail after creating the `PDO` object?

Comment: Just to clarify - are you getting an 'empty object' or is $DBH null?

Comment: @NigelRen, empty object

Comment: @localheinz, when I try $DBH->rollBack I get expection - "Uncaught Error: You're trying to decode an invalid JSON String: <pre>[PDOException] There is no active transaction (0)". Or, it is not because of connection?

Comment: You cannot roll back a transaction that has not been started, already committed, or already been rolled back. That's a different problem.

Comment: The connection is probably established fine. See below answer, which probably should be a comment instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your database contains tables, try running the following:

```
$statement = $DBH->query('SHOW TABLES');

var_dump($statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);
```

If the connection was successfully established, the example above should give you a list of available tables in the database you connected to.

As you noted in the comments, the `PDO` object was created without any exceptions thrown. It just appears to you to be empty, that is probably all.

Comment: Yes, I see a list of all tables, but in console I also get an error - " Error: You're trying to decode an invalid JSON String"

Comment: Error: You're trying to decode an invalid JSON String: array(667) {
  [0]=>
  string(14) "b_admin_notify"
  [1]=>
  string(19) "b_admin_notify_lang"
  [2]=>
  string(12) "b_adv_banner"
  [3]=>
  string(22) "b_adv_banner_2_country"
  [4]=>
  string(18) "b_adv_banner_2_day"

Comment: try {
    $request = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));
    if(empty($request->tin)) return;
    $data = MDGlobalLegalEntries::getGlobalLegalEntries($request->tin);
    echo json_encode(array("data"=>$data, "success"=>true));
}catch(SoapFault  $e){
    $error = MDLang::GetMessage("MSG_EXTERNAL_REFERENCES_ERROR");
    echo json_encode(array("success"=>false, "msg"=>$error));
}
catch (Exception $e) {
    $DBH->rollBack();
    echo json_encode(array("success"=>false, "msg"=>$e->getMessage()));
}

Comment: Hmm. That looks like a whole different issue: a) we don't know what `$request` contains, b) we don't know what `MDGlobalLegalEntries` is, and what it is capable of.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but, turns out, that it is not PDO error)